# XORing a string in C++11

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am trying to implemnt a simple XOR encoding on a string in C++11 (Visual Studio 2017).However, I am having some problems implementing it. The following code would be my standard (C) approach:

```
char* encode(char*  input) {
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        input[i] ^= 0xA; 
   }
   return(input);
 }

 int main(void){
   printf(encode(encode("Hello World!")));
 }
```

But it is no valid code because the string ("Hello Wolrd!") is of type `const char*.`

I tried several things to fix the problem:

1. Cast the string to `(char*)` (i.e., `encode( (char*)"Hello World!")`)
   but it throws an exception when trying to XOR the first byte.
2. Using a temp `char*` in my encoding function, which also resulted in
   stack coruption.

   ```
   char* encode(const char*  input) {
     char temp[128];
     strncpy(temp, input, 128);
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++) {
       temp[i] ^= 0xA;
     }
     return(temp);
    }
   ```
3. I tried using `std:string` but it also did not work out.

   ```
   const char* encode(const char*  input) {  
     std::string temp(input);  
     for (char& c : temp) {
       c  ^= 0xA;
     }
     return(temp.c_str());
   }
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the code using `std::string`?

Comment: `int main(){
   char s[] = "Hello World!";
   printf(encode(encode(s)));
 }`

Comment: Your second example is faulty because you return a pointer to a local variable. The array `temp` goes out of scope immediately when the function returns, leaving the returned pointer invalid.

Comment: The first attempt is faulty because string literals *are* constant (that's why they decay to `const char*`). Attempting to modify one leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The third attempt with `std::string` would be interesting to see, because you probably do something wrong if it doesn't work (perhaps return `c_str()` to a local `std::string` object)? Did you return a `std::string`? Did you attempt to output it using `std::cout` instead of `printf`?

Comment: @Jarod42 It is unsafe to `printf` arbitrary C-strings. The first argument to `printf` is a format-string. Either use `puts` or `printf("%s",string)`.

Comment: I added the std:string code

Comment: Have you tried using `std::string encode(std::string input)` as function signature? And operate on `std::string` entirely without any C-string?

Comment: Now when we see the third attempt, it is basically the same as the second, where you return a pointer to some local variable which go out of scope when the function returns. If you program in C++ then *stop* using old C-style strings completely. Use `std::string` all throughout the code instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `std::string` in function signature, and operate on `std::string` entirely. No C-string involved.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string encode(std::string input)
{
    for (char& c : input) {
        c  ^= 0xA;
    }
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << encode(encode("Hello World!"));
}
```

I recommend against using C-string because it complicates things in these ways:

- String literal (`"Hello World"`) is read-only. You can't modify it.
- If you use local character array (`char[SIZE]`), you can't return it out of the function. The only thing you can do, which is wrong, is to return a dangling pointer to the local array.
- If you allocate a character array dynamically (`malloc` or `new[]`), you must manually manage the the allocated memory, which is clumsy.

`std::string` automatically manages everything for you. Just use it.

Answer (score -1):

Jarod's answer is one of sanest ways to do that. Simply don't pass constants. Or you'll need to create new storage. you can't use local variable for that. Main problem is... that is pure C code.

In C++ you write something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> T encode (const T& s)
{
    using CharT = typename T::value_type;
    T temp;
    for (const CharT& i : s)
    {
        temp += i ^ (CharT)0x0A;
    }
    return temp;
}

template<class T> T encode (T& s)
{
    using CharT = typename T::value_type;
    for (CharT& i : s)
    {
        i = i ^ (CharT)0x0A;
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string str("hello");

    cout << encode(str) << endl;
    cout << encode(string("Hello"))<< endl;
    cout << encode(encode(string("Hello")));
}
```

One overloaded function reuses supplied storage, another one creates a temporal. Memory management is automatic and  confined to `std::string`, usage of templates allows use for strings with different character type or for classes that have same semantic as `std::string`. Of course a `static_assert` can be used to limit usage or specialize template for different types.

Comment: It almost always wrong for a non-void function to also modify its argument. Don't surprise the user.

Comment: @sp2danny viable remark, especially for concept of pure functional approach. "Non-void should not change arguments", "Functions should not have side effects".Yet that exist with nearly every API, especially in POSIX. For example strcpy or strtok do exactly that. Actually non-void functions are rare there.  why? if argument not to be changed it should be constant, otherwise it is implication that it is free to change. Why it's done? to fit various code paradigms. Why I did that? To retain paradigm used by OP.